# Difference between poll and consume in Kafka Confluent library

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

The github examples [page](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AdvancedConsumer/Program.cs) for the Confluent Kafka library lists two methods, namely poll and consume. What is the difference between the two.

I did look at the Consumer implementation in the Confluent Kafka library [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/Consumer.cs) , and feel they're functionally the same, and differ only in terms of what they return.

Poll() calls consume() to see if there is a message ready to be picked up, and if yes, invokes the OnMessage event. Whereas, consume, saves the message in one of it's parameters, and returns a boolean. I feel difference is in implementation, and functionally they're the same 
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/Consumer.cs

Comment: Seems like Consume just fills the output and return true/false if message are returned, and poll does the same but also trigger an event when there are messages...

Answer (score 5):

You are right.
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/3f48e8944242abf631ea8d2cd5698f6e149e0731/src/Confluent.Kafka/Consumer.cs#L1147

`Poll` is the same as `Consume`, just expose message with different semantic. `Consume` will return message in `out` parameter whereas `Poll` return null and will fire `OnMessage` event.

Edit: in v1 there is only `Consume` call left, no more confusion.

Comment: Just an FYI: more recent versions (eg 1.0 beta) no longer have the Poll function w/OnMessage event - it's all just through the Consume function.